# Class and other argument as parameters for method where method defined to take on parameter

Tags: python, class, parameters

i have a code below

```
from dejavu import Dejavu

from dejavu.recognize import FileRecognizer, MicrophoneRecognizer

djv = Dejavu(config)
```

## Recognize audio from a file

```
song = djv.recognize(FileRecognizer, "mp3/Sean-Fournier--Falling-For-You.mp3")
```

## below is from dejavu/recognize.py

```
class BaseRecognizer(object):

    def __init__(self, dejavu):
        self.dejavu = dejavu
        self.Fs = fingerprint.DEFAULT_FS

    def _recognize(self, *data):
        matches = []
        for d in data:
            matches.extend(self.dejavu.find_matches(d, Fs=self.Fs))
        return self.dejavu.align_matches(matches)

    def recognize(self):
        pass  # base class does nothing


class FileRecognizer(BaseRecognizer):

    def __init__(self, dejavu):
        super(FileRecognizer, self).__init__(dejavu)

    def recognize_file(self, filename):
        frames, self.Fs, file_hash = decoder.read(filename, self.dejavu.limit)

        t = time.time()
        match = self._recognize(*frames)
        t = time.time() - t

        if match:
            match['match_time'] = t

        return match

    def recognize(self, filename):
        return self.recognize_file(filename)
```

I don't undersand how recognize takes class Filereognizer and also filename where recognizer is defined as

def recognize(self, filename):

and takes only filename as a parameter. can someone explain how this work and what it actually does???

---

thanks to @daniel here is my follow up question

```
def recognize(self, recognizer, *options, **kwoptions):
    r = recognizer(self)
    return r.recognize(*options, **kwoptions)
```

this is recognizer under Djavu class and I am thinking "self" from line "r = recognizer(self)" is what make recognizer(under Dejavu class) can receive FileRecognizer class as a parameter right?

this is from dejavu(audiofingerprint software) github and link is below :
https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu

Comment: `djv` is an instance of DejaVu, not Recognizer, so you're calling the recognize method of that class not the one you've shown.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you!